# Check if Ids exist in database before attach

Tags: php, laravel

I select an array with categories via `json_decode` and attach them to the article.

```
public static function setArticleCategory(Request $request) {
    
        $article = Article::where('id', $request->article_id)->first();

        if(!$article){
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Article not found'
                ], 404);
        }

        $categories_ids = json_decode($request->categories_ids);

        $article->categories()->attach($categories_ids);
    
        return response()->json([
            'message' => $categories_ids
        ], 200);
    }
```

The question is, how can I check in `categories_ids`, for example, if one of the selected categories does not exist in the array?

Comment: where do you get the "selected category" from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest way would be to use count()

```
$categories_ids = json_decode($request->categories_ids);
if (count($categories_ids) != Category::whereKey($categories_ids)->count()) {
    //return error.
}
```

It would not tell you wich one is the non existing category, but it will trigger an error if at least one of them doesnt exist.

**Edit (comment)***

if you want to ignore the non existing IDs, use this

```
$categories_ids = json_decode($request->categories_ids);

$categoryPK = (new Category())->getKeyName();
$categories_ids = Category::whereKey($categories_ids)->pluck($categoryPK)->toArray();
```

It will return an array of ids that exists in the database based on the input (you need to check for empty array after that).

Comment: But let's say we enter the array [1, 2, 3, 4], and there are 4 non-existent category in it. How do I make sure that all existing categories are added and 4 are simply ignored?

Comment: @Kim2000 added to the answer what you are after.